# MassTransit compensation failure - deadletter?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm new to MassTransit (using rabbitmq), so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I just wanted to know how one is meant to handle an unsuccessful compensation? So all retries failed, i.e. no compensation succeeded - I would imagine the message should go to a deadletter queue of sorts for me to manually retry at a later date once ok to retry again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a routing slip, and during compensation of an activity an exception is thrown, the `RoutingSlipCompensationFailed` event is published. At that point, there is no retry, no error/dead-letter, etc. The routing slip is considered "ended" at that point, and the distributed transaction which faulted (thus causing the compensation methods to be invoked) is over.

When using routing slips, it's important to observe the events produced by the routing slip runtime (activity completed/compensated/faulted, as well as overall routing slip completed/faulted/compensation failed) - typically using a saga.

I'd suggest looking at the Demo-Registration sample on my GitHub to get an idea of how to use sagas in combination with routing slips to perform reliable distributed transactions.

https://github.com/phatboyg/Demo-Registration

Comment: I see that Compensate() is called indefinitely, if I do try catch and  return context.Failed(myException) in the catch all exception block. Is this expected?

Comment: My above observation happens if try block always fails. The message seems to be stuck in an indefinite rollback.

Comment: Update: My above comment is applicable to 4.0.1. After upgrading to 5.1.5, it works like Chris has mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The message will go to the poison queue if retry policies were unable to help processing the message and there is no redelivery (second-level retry) configured. Poison queues are called "error queues" in MassTransit.

The poison queue has the same queue name as your receive endpoint queue, with `_error` suffix.

Deadletter is something else, it is for messages that were received by the endpoint but the endpoint doesn't know how to handle it. Deadletter queues are called "skipped message queues" in MassTransit and have the suffix `_skipped`.

**Update:** this is the generic MassTransit behaviour. Courier works differently, as Chris described in another answer. It wasn't clear for me that the question is about using routing slips.